# ido-mode causing emacs to hang

Tags: emacs

My emacs is suddenly hanging on `ido-mode`... Even when I start up with:

```
emacs -Q
```

and then do:

```
M-x ido-mode
```

it still hangs. I have used `ido-mode` in the past without any problems, but suddenly I can't get it to load...

GNU Emacs 24.1.1

I've never had this problem in the past and I haven't changed my configuration at all. How do I solve the hanging issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and stumbled upon the following solution: https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/issues/102

Basically, a "stale" `~/.ido.last` will cause `ido-mode` to hang. Remove it and you should be good to go.

```
rm ~/.ido.last
```

Comment: i just downloaded 24.2.2 and didn't have this issue, nor did i in 24.1.x either. sorry man.

Comment: yeah it doesn't happen very often. actually I've only seen it happen once but couldn't find the solution, hence the self-answer here :)